# Xamarian (Android): Issue installing Emulators. Need clarity regarding ADO.Net with Sqlite using disconnected architecture

Tags: c#, android

I started studying your developer guides available on website and successfully connected toSQLite via SQLite Net and Ado.net. I am using physical device to deploy the application using ADB.

But I am having few queries regarding the development. I would appreciate if you can clarify me on them.

Query1: I used Ado.net using DataReader that is connected architecture. Can we do it using SqlDataAdapters and Dataset i.e. disconnected architecture?

Query2: I tried installing Visual studio emulator on my Windows 8 and Visual studio 2015 as IDE. But it gives me installation errors.
 I also did some google search but it says it is not possible to install it on windows 8. Please suggest me about emulators.

Answer (score 0):

For emulators you can use Genymotion Emulator https://www.genymotion.com/. It is the best I think.